# Reading a CSV file and cannot print out the ending double quotation mark around my final value

Tags: bash, shell-script, terminal

I am trying to convert the lines of a .csv file (created in google sheets and downloaded to my local machine) into a javascript object.  I am able to get all the fields output correctly except for the very last field which refuses to print the final double quotation mark.  In addition, the output to the terminal is misplacing my ending "]" and placing it at the beginning of the "comps" line (as opposed to the end).  WHy won't the final double quote print out correctly?

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

list_file="input.csv"
destination_file="output.js"

IFS=","

while read field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 field6 field7 field8 field9 field10 field11 field12 field13 field14
do
    echo '"'${field8}'": { r: "'${field2}'", g: "'${field3}'", b: "'${field4}'", hex: "'${field5}'", code: "'${field1}'", 
    desc: "'${field9}'",
    comps: ["'${field10}'", "'${field11}'", "'${field12}'", "'${field13}'", "'${field14}'"]
    },' >> $destination_file
done < $list_file

echo "};" >> $destination_file
```

Output for one line looks like this:

```
"#288": { r: "x", g: "x", b: "x", hex: "x", code: "XXXX", 
    desc: "description here",
"], comps: ["#1", "#2", "#3", "#4", "#5
    },
```

On the 3rd line the final double quotation and ending bracket are being printed first.

In addition, when testing each individual field by using:

```
echo '"' $field14 '"'
```

I get the same output (no ending double quotation) for ONLY the last field.  However all the other fields print as intended.

Comment: is the space between `#!` and `/usr/bin/env` intended? Because I don't think it's correct.

Comment: it was intentional, and I tested by removing the space, but still the same outcome.  all my scripts contain that same line.

Comment: Just looked it up, wikipedia says the whitespace is *optional*, so it's OK! Thanks, I've learned something today!

Comment: Your code does not produce the output you claim - perhaps the problem is with the input data

Comment: perhaps your data has CRLF line endings

Comment: ,how can I best deal with that?  Can i remove the carriage returns and resave the file?

Comment: yes, or read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891076/how-to-convert-windows-end-of-line-in-unix-end-of-line-cr-lf-to-lf) - `dos2unix` would be my suggestion, or just use `tr`

Comment: Will check it now @Bravo

Comment: Any idea why the final line in my CSV is not being output at all?

Comment: js isn't just for web browsers, so why not write your script in javascript? shell is a terrible language for text processing, while javascript isn't a great language for command-line tools, it's pretty good at text processing and has library routines for parsing csv and for storing its data structures in text files.  And you seem to already know js since you want your csv file converted into a js object.   `awk` and `perl` would also be good choices, actually better than js since they're good at text processing and writing command-line tools.

Comment: Thanks @cas i’m actually trying to write a script now to run using node that can process another csv file that doesn’t have consistent values in each field

Answer (score 1):

Shell is a terrible language for text and data processing.  Shell's job is to co-ordinate the execution of other programs to do work (and it's good at that), not to do the work itself.  Use a language better suited to text (and CSV) processing.  For example, perl:

```perl
$ cat csv-to-js.pl 
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Text::CSV qw(csv);

my $fmt = <<__EOF__;
"%s": { r: "%s", g: "%s", b: "%s", hex: "%s", code: "%s",
    desc: "%s",
    comps: ["%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s"],
    },
__EOF__

# default to reading stdin if no args are supplied
push @ARGV, '/dev/stdin' unless (@ARGV);

my $csv = Text::CSV->new();

foreach my $f (@ARGV) {
  open my $fh, "<", $f or die "$f: $!";
  while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
    printf $fmt, @$row[7,1..4,0,8,9..13]; # perl arrays start from 0, not 1
  };
  close $fh;
}
```

This uses the [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/release/Text-CSV) module, which is not included with core perl, it needs to be installed separately.   On Debian and derivatives like Ubuntu & Mint, install it with `sudo apt-get install libtext-csv-perl`.  Other Linux distros will have similarly named packages, otherwise install it with `cpan`.

The script creates a format string for printf, opens the CSV file(s) listed on the command line, reads and parses each line, and prints them with printf.

BTW, this script works whether the lines end with LF only (unix text files) or CR/LF (dos/windows text files).

Sample input:

```
$ cat input.csv 
XXXX,x,x,x,x,6,7,"#288","description here","#1","#2","#3","#4","#5"
YYYY,x,x,x,x,6,7,"#289","another description here","#1","#2","#3","#4","#5"
ZZZZ,x,x,x,x,6,7,"#290","and another description here","#1","#2","#3","#4","#5"
```

sample run:

```
$ ./csv-to-js.pl input.csv 
"#288": { r: "x", g: "x", b: "x", hex: "x", code: "XXXX",
    desc: "description here",
    comps: ["#1", "#2", "#3", "#4", "#5"],
    },
"#289": { r: "x", g: "x", b: "x", hex: "x", code: "YYYY",
    desc: "another description here",
    comps: ["#1", "#2", "#3", "#4", "#5"],
    },
"#290": { r: "x", g: "x", b: "x", hex: "x", code: "ZZZZ",
    desc: "and another description here",
    comps: ["#1", "#2", "#3", "#4", "#5"],
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments I added this line to remove the CRLF line ending on the final field and the code printed as should.

```
field14=$(echo $field14 | sed 's/\r//g')
```